# Conditional numerical integration boundaries

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a multidimensional integration of the form:

```
  somefunc[t] = NIntegrate[ otherfunc[x, y, z, t ],
  {z, z1[t], z2[t]}, {y, y1[t, z], y2[t, z]}, {x, x1[t, z, y], x2[t, z, y]}];
```

This needs to be evaluated only when $z2 > z1$, $y2 > y1$ and $x2 > x1$. However mathematica still evaluates the integrand backwards even if $y2 < y1$. My question is how to tell `NIntegrate` to simply give 0 in such cases and move on the next integration step. I tried to modify the upper integration boundary as follows:

```
 y2p[t, z] = Max[y1[t, z], y2[t, z]]
```

But this is not accepted by Mathematica as an integration boundary. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your complete and valid code.

Comment: Are you missing a pattern from the LHS?  Looks like `somefunc[t] =` should be `somefunc[t_] :=`.  It also looks like most answers have copied this problem without noticing it.

Answer (score 9):

A better option than using `Boole` would be to use `Piecewise`. Using that you can define a function that returns 0 when your conditions aren't met and `otherfunc` otherwise.

So, define a function `otherfunc2` and integrate that:

```
otherfunc2[x_, y_, z_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[
  {
   {otherfunc[x, y, z, t],
    z1[t] <=z<= z2[t] && y1[t, z] <=y<= y2[t, z] && x1[t, z, y] <=x<= x2[t, z, y]},
   {0, True}
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try

```
   somefunc[t] = NIntegrate[ 
   Boole[z1[t] <= z <= z2[t]
   && y1[t, z] <= y <= y2[t, z] 
   && x1[t, z, y] <= x <= x2[t, z, y]]
   otherfunc[x, y, z, t ],
   {z, z0, z1},{y, y0, y1}, {x, x0, x1}];
```

where the integration limits are appropriate constants.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is well defined whether `y1 > y2`, `y1 < y2`, or one or both of `y1` and `y2` is complex (so that `<` and `>` have no meaning). That's why NIntegrate proceeds with integration in any of these cases.

Therefore if you want these cases to return a special value, such as 0, you should do it manually with something like this:

```
somefunc[t] := If[z1[t] < z2[t] && ..., NIntegrate[...], 0];
```

(Definitely use `:=` instead of `=`.)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do something like

```
somefunc[t] = NIntegrate[ otherfunc[x, y, z, t ],
  {z, z1[t], Max[z1[t], z2[t]]}, {y, y1[t, z], Max[y1[t, z], y2[t, z]]}, 
  {x, x1[t, z, y], Max[x1[t, z, y], x2[t, z, y]]}];
```