# NIntegrating within an Ellipsoid

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

I need to numerically integrate an expensive positive-definite function over a 2D domain. I know by other ways that the function is basically zero for values outside the following ellipse:

`Ellipsoid[center,Sqrt[Eigenvalues[matrix]], Eigenvectors[matrix]]`

How do I tell Mathematica to integrate only within the ellipsoid?

---

Here is what I got using your nice suggestions (timings are normalized to the slowest):

100 sec - integration over the rectangle circumscribing the ellipse

55 sec - using Boole to integrate only over ellipse (@b.gatessucks)

47 sec - directly limiting the domain to the ellipse (@whuber)

41 sec - mapping the ellipse to a unit circle (@Jens)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional numerical integration boundaries](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/conditional-numerical-integration-boundaries)

Comment: @R.M The questions are awfully similar, but IMO there is a subtle  difference. The question here is about restricting *calculations* to a certain area whereas the other question is about *totally preventing* evaluation whenever the higher bounds are smaller than the lower bounds.

Comment: Could you time, too, for comparison, Jens's method of using elliptical coordinates? Having a complete comparison of all the methods would be edifying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use [elliptical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system)? That's what they are there for.

For example, if your function is `f[x_,y_]`, then you define the coordinate transformation

```
x[u_, v_]:= Cos[v] Cosh[u];
y[u_, v_]:= Sin[v] Sinh[u];
```

The Jacobian is `Sin[v]^2 + Sinh[u]^2`, so you simply do the integral like this:

```
NIntegrate[
 f[x[u, v], y[u, v]] (Sin[v]^2 + Sinh[u]^2), {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

That's the basic idea. You can always rotate and scale your function arguments to fit within this particular ellipse which has axis lengths of `Cosh[1]` and `Sinh[1]`, respectively. You can also adjust the integration limit in `{u, 0, 1}` to something other than `1` depending on the eccentricity of the ellipse. These steps are easy once you understand the coordinate system.

You can also do all this using the `VectorAnalysis` package, but I'd say that is overkill for this relatively simple problem.

**Rescaling to a circle in 2D**

In fact, you may also want to look into just rescaling your `x` and `y` coordinates to fit into a *circle* and use polar coordinates... (that also generalizes more easily to higher dimensions).

There isn't exactly one built-in function to do the rescaling, but you can probably find all you need by starting at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/composition-of-transformationfunctions). I'll just describe the logic:

Assume you have already figured out the semimajor and -minor axes (`vec1` and `vec2`) as well as the center (in a variable `center`) of the ellipse. Then you can figure out the rotation angle required to make `vec1` the x-axis, leading to a rotation `R`. The scale transformation `T` that you need is given by the lengths of `vec1` and `vec2`, resp.

Now compose your function `f[x,y]` with these transformations. This transformation introduces a Jacobian given by the product `Norm[vec] * Norm[vec2]`.

The final step is to go to polar coordinates which introduces an additional factor `r` (the radial coordinate).

Polar coordinates are probably best in this case, unless you plan on doing other manipulations with your function that go beyond integration.

**Edit**

Turns out it's almost more difficult to describe the transformations in words than it is to do it in Mathematica. So I'm adding the code now:

```
rescaling = Composition[TranslationTransform[center], 
   RotationTransform[{{1, 0}, vec1}], 
   ScalingTransform[{Norm[vec1], Norm[vec2]}]]
```

This is now used in the integral of your function which I assume to be defined as

```
f[{x_, y_}] := ...
```

(note that the argument is a single list representing the point). With this, it only remains to write the integral

```
integrand = Composition[f, rescaling];
polarIntegrand[r_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
     integrand[{r Cos[a], r Sin[a]}] r;
NIntegrate[
  polarIntegrand[r,a], 
   {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}] Norm[vec1] Norm[vec2]
```

Here, I've tweaked the integrand a little to make sure we don't get slowed down by Mathematica attempting to symbolically simplify it. The `?NumericQ` rules that out. That should be all you need.

Comment: `NIntegrate` also does some sort of coordinate transformation to match the shape of the domain specified with `Boole` (check the points where it evaluates the integral using the code from Heike's comment).  Also, it seems to be smart enough to detect any symmetries of the integrand and use them to reduce the number of points.

Comment: Well, there isn't always a suitable coordinate transformation, so Boole is a good general approach. But elliptical domains are special, and one should exploit that whenever possible. Not knowing how clever Boole is, I instead trust my own cleverness...

Comment: do you think it is gonna be faster in this way?

Comment: is there a built-in way to change coordinates in the case of rotated and translated ellipsoid? I like the idea of mapping the ellipsoid to a sphere

Comment: I'll try to add some more to this post to answer this question.

Comment: (+1) Elliptical coordinates work well when the integrand *simplifies* when re-expressed in those coordinates.  (They are excellent for certain problems in classical physics or quantum mechanics, for instance.)  Whether or not the introduction of the Jacobian (which symbolically could be a terrible complication) is a problem for *numerical* integration is probably a matter for further analysis in any particular problem.  It might or might not reflect an improved approach.

Comment: Simplification doesn't automatically affect the speed of NIntegrate.

Comment: Jens: Agreed.  But it indirectly affects the speed: the elliptical coordinates will naturally cause the edges of the ellipse to be inspected more frequently (at least at first).  In this application, most of the high function values are near the center of the ellipse, suggesting that some coordinate systems could lead to more efficient sampling than others.  But in general that's hard to predict and it's probably only a small influence on efficiency.

Comment: Hard to predict indeed. Anyway, the polar coordinate approach was better, I guess. In statistics, you'd simply call this "standardizing a distribution."

Comment: @Jens could you please generalize your code to ellipsoid of `n` dimensions?

Answer (score 12):

If you know the equation defining your ellipsoid you could use `Boole[]` to constrain the integration domain :

```
myF[x_,y_]=Abs[x+y]
NIntegrate[Boole[(x/3)^2 + (y/2)^2 <= 1] myF[x,y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Note that this will actually prevent `myF[x, y]` from being evaluated outside the domain specified by `Boole`.  This feature of `NIntegrate` is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntroduction.html#105041303).

Comment: This really doesn't help reducing calculation time as asked by the OP.  In fact, adding `Boole` *increases* calculation time 6-fold. This is logical as adding `Boole` does **not** prevent the evaluation of the expensive function outside of the area where the argument of `Boole` is true.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Actually, it does prevent the function from being evaluated outside the region. Try for example something like `f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y; Reap[NIntegrate[Boole[x + y < .5] f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]], _, ListPlot[#2] &]`, then the plot shows that the integrand is only evaluated in the region where `Boole[]!=0`.

Comment: @Heike OK, I didn't check that. I based my conclusion on the timing. In the given example here adding Boole really doesn't work to reduce calculation time.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I guess it depends how expensive the calculation of `myF` is whether it's worthwhile to use `Boole` or not.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I have a hunch that when you add `Boole`, it's the symbolic preprocessing that takes time.  Mathematica does a lot of smart things including checking the symmetries of the domain and the integrand to reduce the number of points where it needs to be evaluated.  Check the link I edited in (I was surprised).  Constraining the domain also influences the location of points where its evaluated (i.e. it doesn't just numerically *filter* out the points that are outside the domain---it seems to use symbolic methods to generate them inside the domain.)

Comment: @szabolcs NIntegrate is indeed cleverer than I thought.

Comment: @Sjoerd Mathematica is full of features that are not so easy to find because they are not associated with separate functions but special behaviour of common functions.  Using `Composition` on `TranformationFunction`s was new to me too.

Answer (score 11):

For total control over integration, **sweep over the ellipse along the eigendirections**.  To get the integral right, it is essential to use unit-length eigenvectors.  This code shows a discrete version of the sweep, to help you visualize it:

```
m = {{2, 1}, {1, 3}}; (* Matrix *)
c = {3, 5};           (* Center *)

ev = Sqrt[Eigenvalues[m]]; (* Semi-axes *)
evec = Eigenvectors[m];    (* Principal directions, unnormalized *)
evec = DiagonalMatrix[1/Norm[#] & /@ evec].evec; (* Unit eigenvectors *)
With[{k = 20}, 
 ListPlot[Flatten[
   Table[c + {s, t}.evec,
     {s, -ev[[1]], ev[[1]], ev[[1]]/k}, 
     {t, -ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2], ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2], 
          ev[[2]]/k }
   ], 1], 
  AspectRatio -> Sqrt[ev[[1]] / ev[[2]]], AxesOrigin -> {1.5, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[c], Thick, Darker[Red], 
    Arrow[{c, c + {ev[[1]], 0}.evec}], Darker[Blue], 
    Arrow[{c, c + {0, ev[[2]]}.evec}]}]
 ]
```

This draws the first axis in red and the second in blue, each to the tip of the ellipse, on top of the dots created by the double-sweep across the eigendirections:

[image: Ellipse]

**Integration is done in a similar fashion.**  Here's the area of the ellipse:

```
cnst = NIntegrate[1, {s, -ev[[1]], ev[[1]]}, 
         {t, -ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2/ev[[1]]^2], ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2/ev[[1]]^2]}]
```

It returns 7.02481, equal to $\sqrt{5}\pi$, as it should (the determinant of `m` is $5$).

As a further check we can recover the ellipse parameters from its first two moments.  E.g.,

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, {p_, q_}] := x[[1]]^p x[[2]]^q; (* For the (p,q) moment *)
ParallelTable[
 NIntegrate[
   f[c + {s, t}.evec, pq], 
     {s, -ev[[1]], ev[[1]]},
     {t, -ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2], ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2] }
  ] / cnst, 
  {pq, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}]
```

This returns the center, `{3., 5.}`, as it should.

```
ParallelTable[
 4 NIntegrate[
    f[{s, t}.evec, pq], 
      {s, -ev[[1]], ev[[1]]},
      {t, -ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2], ev[[2]] Sqrt[1 - s^2 / ev[[1]]^2] }
   ] / cnst, 
   {pq, {{2, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}}}]
```

These three central second moments (scaled up by 4) ought to return the coefficients of the matrix `m`.  Indeed, the result is `{2., 1., 3.}`, exactly as expected.  The visualization and these checks should give you confidence that this technique is correct.

Comment: Thanks: I fixed the expression and then checked it by pasting it from here back into *Mathematica* and executing it.  BTW, replacing `NIntegrate` by `Integrate` works in all these examples (but takes a few seconds).

Comment: Why don't you use [`Orthogonalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orthogonalize.html) to normalize the eigenvectors? As they're guaranteed to be orthogonal already, it will just normalize them. Also, there's [`Normalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normalize.html) which can be mapped across them to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions--I am grateful to learn about `Normalize` and welcome any code improvements you might ever have the inclination to volunteer in the future.  (It seems *Mathematica* has loads of stuff built in, but first you have to discover it.)  But in this case we probably shouldn't care about elegance or efficiency, because computing the integration directions and limits is O(1) overhead for what promises to be a long painful integration; the primary concern therefore has to be correctness of code.  (If it weren't for that, this answer would have been about two lines long. :-)