# Composition of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, function-construction

I have a number of rotations computed by `rot = RotationTransform[theta, point]`, and I would like to compose them to produce one function that is the composition of all the rotations.  I need this function in a form that I can then use in, say, `FindMinimum[]`.

I solved my problem by using `TransformationMatrix[rot]`, multiplying all the matrices, and defining a function based on that.  But it would be cleaner to create one function that is the composition of the others, rather than take the detour through matrices.  Ideally I would input a list of `theta, point' values, and get back a function that is the composition of all those rotations.

I'd appreciate learning how to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post the code for the functions your have. Then someone can suggest how to compose them.

Comment: Why would you not want to work with the matrices directly? Seems like a straightforward way to compose the combined rotation.

Comment: @David: I didn't want to bias the answers to my specific situation.  The various rotations are computed in separate parts of the code, and only lashed together at the end.  I would have to contrive an example to make it independent of my details.

Comment: @Yves: It works perfectly by multiplying matrices.  I just thought that was an inelegant solution.

Comment: Ultimately, the matrices will get multiplied together, anyway. The question is whether or not you do it yourself.

Comment: @Joseph Looks like several people were able to answer your question without having access to the specific functions.

Comment: @David If the more general question has a good answer, like in this case, it's more useful to have the more general question.  The only problem is that the asker can't easily guess if a general solution is possible. :-)

Comment: I have learned much from this discussion--Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function your looking for is [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html) which does exactly what you would like it to do. For instance,

```
{rot1, rot2} = MapThread[RotationTransform, {{theta1,theta1},{point1,point2}}]
composed = Composition @@ %
```

> ```
> Composition[
>      RotationTransform[theta1, point1], 
>      RotationTransform[theta1, point2]
>   ]
> ```

which can then be used like `rot1` and `rot2` would, e.g. `composed[ {x, y, z} ]`. From some experiments, it seems that `Composition` will combine multiple `TransformationFunction` into a single `TransformationFunction`, e.g.

```
Composition[ RotationTransform[ Pi/2 ], RotationTransform[ Pi/2] ] ]
```

simplifies to

```
RotationTransform[ Pi ]
```

---

Here is a specific example using the following rotations

```
RotationTransform[Pi/2, {1, 0}]
RotationTransform[Pi/2, {1, 1}]
composed = Composition @@ {%, %%}
```

which gives the output (it's in picture form as the output is displayed using boxes):

[image]

Now, applying them one at a time to a triangle, using the following code

```
FoldList[
  {EdgeForm[Black], White, #2[#1]} &, 
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}], 
  {# &, 
   GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Pi/2, {1, 0}]] &, 
   GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Pi/2, {1, 1}]] &}
][[2 ;;]] //
GraphicsRow[
 Graphics[#, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}] & /@ # 
]&
```

gives

[image]

Using the composition directly via

```
Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black], White, 
   GeometricTransformation[
       Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}], 
       composed]
  }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

gives the identical end result

[image]

Two things to note here. First, the functions are entered into `Composition` in reverse order of application, i.e. the first function to be applied is last, and the last function is first. Second, I made use of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) to apply the rotations to a `Graphics` primitive.

Comment: If you supply explicit values for the points like `point1={u1, u2}` the result is properly evaluated as well.

Comment: @YvesKlett actually, yes it does. You can combine any of the specializations of `TransformFunction` and they will be made into a single unit.

Comment: Would you mind editing in an example with explicit rotation points? Should be quite instructive for future browsing.

Comment: @YvesKlett added an example with graphics for visual oriented people.

Comment: Wonderful!  This is exactly what I sought.  Thanks!

Comment: @Hector, my use of `TransformationFunction` was deliberate. `RotationTransform` puts out a `TransformationFunction` which can then be composed. The change to `transformationFunction` loses that meaning. Reverting the edit.

Comment: @rcollyer: My mistake. I did not know that Mathematica has `TransformationFunction` and `TransformationFunctions` with rather different uses and scopes. A Google search sent me here, so I assumed it was a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you want a built-in function `Composition`.  Having two functions `f` and `g`, where `g` depends on two arguments it works like this :

```
Composition[f, g] @@ {x, y}
```

> ```
> f[g[x, y]]
> ```

E.g.

```
g[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x^2 y]
f[z_]     := 1/2 Tan[z]
Composition[f, g] @@ {x, y}
```

> ```
> (x^2 y)/2
> ```

`Composition` works with many functions as well, e.g. :

```
Composition[f1, f2, f3, f4] @@ {x, y, z}
```

> ```
> f1[f2[f3[f4[x, y, z]]]]
> ```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `Composition` will evaluate when transformation functions are passed to it.  I think you should give an example using transformation functions to make this explicit.  This is a special behaviour of `Composition`, specific to `TransformationFunction`s.

Comment: Composition is also mentioned in the help under guide/GeometricTransforms. In this case it is a neat thing, but the GeometricTransformation framework can be a bit opaque IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much, two equivalent answers!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke You are welcome.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you emphasize what are your objections if any ?

Comment: @Artes My meaning was that I was surprised and delighted to find that `Compose[f,g]` does indeed auto-simplify *if* `f` and `g` are `TransformationFunction`s, like rcollyer showed in his answer.  I read your answer first and thought that it's less efficient than hand-multiplying the matrices and construction a new `TranformationFunction` from them.  But I checked if `Composition` would actually evaluate, and surprise---it did!  This only happens for `TranformationFunction` objects, and it is not obvious, so I asked you to include it (but it seems rcollyer did first).

Comment: @Szabolcs If you check my example with `g[x_,y_]:=2ArcTan[x^2 y]` then you'll need to evaluate something like this `Composition[f, g] @@ {x, y}// TrigExpand // Simplify`, but I think this is a quite general issue, so in case of `TranformationFunction` similar things can be needed.

Comment: @Artes No, it's not an issue with `TransformationFunction`s, only with general functions.  `Composition[f, g]` evaluates by itself when `f` and `g` are `TransformationFunction`s.  This make a huge difference performance-wise when you apply the composed function to lots of arguments.  I hope now it's more clear what I meant.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, but in the context of the question it is not clear whether there are or not general functions.

Comment: To me, "I have a number of rotations computed by rot = RotationTransform[theta, point], and I would like to compose them" and "I solved my problem by using TransformationMatrix[rot], multiplying all the matrices" suggest that the OP is specifically interested in linear transformation functions (actually rotations) and wants to avoid the overhead of applying several rotations when they can be combined into a single one ... This is why I didn't answer with `Composition`.  However, it was precisely your answer that made me realize that `Composition` is the best solution here after all.

Answer (score 5):

One more thing that may be useful when working with `Composition`: to include a transformation that does nothing, use `Identity`.

You may ask why you'd ever need that. An example is given in this post for a shadow projection function:
[How to make a drop-shadow for a Graphics3D objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-make-a-drop-shadow-for-graphics3d-objects/1030#1030)

There is a transformation in the `Composition` that is supposed to be left out under certain conditions. The link also illustrates how much simpler `Composition` is than the alternative of adding vectors and multiplying matrices.