# Function Interpolation with Automatic / Algorithmic Values Mesh

Tags: functions, interpolation, mesh

I have an underlying function f(x,y,z) that is computationally intensive, but is smooth and continuous. I'm needing to find the function values along a line in xyz.  Currently, I'm calculating f at discrete steps and I'm wondering if there is a way to get *Mathematica* to automatically chose the step size and work out an interpolating function based on some inputs like how accurate I need it to be and what the initial step size should be.  I'm thinking it would kind of work like the mesh function does in plotting by evaluating functions more often in areas of higher complexity.

Does anyone have any ideas where to start?

Comment: Have you tried `FunctionInterpolation`? It takes many of the same options as `Interpolation`. I find I often have to use them since automation fails for all but simple functions however. It might be helpful to give your function even if it is complicated.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216/5) and the answer. I believe this is a duplicate, although I'd wait to close it as such. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2947/57) may be useful too.

Comment: Based on its documentation, `FunctionInterpolation` definitely *should* do what Chris is asking for.  However, as Andy mentions, it's very brittle.  See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564556/increasing-mathematica-functioninterpolation-accuracy-domain/37263804#37263804).  Still, playing around with its options is probably less work than reverse-engineering the `Plot` function.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function to do this. However, what you can do is a heavy abuse of `Part` to extract the points from a `Plot` object:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> [image]

The `InputForm`, i.e. how Mathematica sees this picture internally, looks like like this:

> ```
> Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[{{1.2*^-7, 1.2*^-7}, [long list of points]} ... (options etc)
> ```

You can now extract these points by using `Part`, i.e. `[[ ]]`:

```
points = g[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {0.01, 0.01}, {0.02, 0.02}, {0.03, 0.03}, {0.06, 0.06}, ...
> ```

This can now be used for a `ListPlot` to visualize the points extracted:

```
ListPlot[points]
```

> [image]

The density of points and the recursion can be set usual when plotting, i.e. `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.

Remarks:

1. I've rounded the values above heavily so it doesn't blow up the answer. Usually the numbers are much more precise.
2. Bear in mind that this does extractions from `Plot` that are not supposed to be done. For this reason, you should be especially careful setting plotting parameters and things like these, as I could imagine that some of them may change the structure of the `Graphics` object you're extracting the data from.

Comment: Here are some issues I see. First, `Plot` will give numbers to machine precision and only machine precision. Second, `Plot` cannot be used to find values for a function f(x,y,z) assuming this is a plot in 4 dimensions. Finally, any attempt to extract parts from the input form of an object can change from version to version so don't expect it to work if you upgrade. All that being said, I do this myself all the time +1 :)

Comment: I agree, it's a pretty hacky workaround. I really wish they included the subdivision algorithm.

Comment: @Andy How about evaluating the function afresh using the sampling points (I.e. x values) from the plot to overcome machine precision?

Comment: @JxB I had commented with some code to do just that but it took up so much space I deleted it :) I don't know but it might be worthwhile to set `WorkingPrecision` on `Plot` before hand (even though the results will need to be coerced via `SetPrecision`)

Comment: @AndyRoss an $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ function can be plotted using `Plot`, provided you parameterize it. The OP wants this along a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that's covered. Also, you can increase the `WorkingPrecision` of `Plot` to go beyond machine precision.

Comment: @rcollyer true about `WorkingPrecision` but the points will always be returned as MachinePrecision regardless what `WorkingPrecision` you use so you need to coerce them after the fact.

Comment: @AndyRoss I was not aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I want to do cheap adaptive sampling along a function, I used to do what David did back in old versions of *Mathematica*. Nowadays, I proceed like so:

```
pts = Cases[Normal[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> All]], Point[pt_] :> pt, ∞];
```

`ListPlot[pts]` should yield an image similar to the one in David's answer. A similar procedure can be done for parametrically-defined plane curves (via `ParametricPlot[]`) and space curves (via `ParametricPlot3D[]`).