# Integrating with multiple indicator functions

Tags: syntax, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I am trying to calculate an integral involving multiple indicator functions, such as:

$$ h(u,v,w) = -\int_0^1 J^{\prime\prime}(s) (I_{(0,s]}(u) - s)(I_{(0,s]}(v) - s)(I_{(0,s]}(w) - s)\, dF^{-1}(s)$$

where $0 < u, v, w < 1$ and

$$\begin{align}
J(s) &= 6s(1-s)\\
F(s) &= 1/[1 + \exp[-s]]\\
F^{-1}(s) &= -\log[-1 + 1/s]\\
\end{align}
$$

Here is my code:

```
Js = 6 s (1 - s) (*weight function*)
FDJs = D[Js, s] (*first derivative of Js*)
SDJs = D[FDJs, s] (*second derivative of Js*)
Fs = 1/(1 + Exp[-(s)]) (*Fs*)
Finv = -Log[-1 + 1/s] (*F inverse*)
DFinv = D[Finv, s] (*derivative of F inverse*)
h = -Integrate[
    SDJs*(Boole[u <= s] - s)*(Boole[v <= s] - s)*(Boole[w <= s] - 
    s) DFinv, {s, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> {0 < u < 1 , 0 < v < 1, 0 < w < 1}]
```

I get some output, but I am not sure if the syntax is correct especially for the indicator function.

Answer (score 5):

A better construct for your indicator function would be using `Piecewise`. So you'd define an indicator function $I_{(a,b]}$ as:

```
indicator[a_, b_][x_] := Piecewise[{{1, a < x <= b}, {0, True}}]
```

However, there are other issues in your code that could be improved.

- First, avoid using capital letters for your variables/functions. This is because Mathematica uses that notation for its own functions and invariably, you'll (at some point) be bitten by it.
- Define your functions by appropriately scoping the variable. For example you defined `Js = 6 s (1 - s)`. However, if `s` had a pre-existing value (you never know... sometimes it could be in a different notebook but shared context), then you're assigning to `Js` the result based on *that* value of `s`.
- Use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when you use `D`. Otherwise, you'll end up calculating the derivative at each integration point. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1305/5) for an example of why this matters.

My suggested rewrite of the definitions part of your problem would be something like this:

```
j[s_] := 6 s (1 - s);      (*weight function*)
j1[s_] = D[j[s], s] ;      (*first derivative of Js*)
j2[s_] = D[j[s], {s, 2}];  (*second derivative of Js*)
f[s_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-(s)]) (*Fs*)
finv[s_] := -Log[-1 + 1/s] (*F inverse*)
finv1[s_] = D[finv[s], s]; (*derivative of F inverse*)
```

You can try working with this and the indicator function above to see if it makes any difference or if you're getting the answer you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will rewrite the definitions.

Comment: @wayan I'm not so sure you should replace `Boole` with `Piecewise`. As the comments under [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2838/57) show, MMA does smart things when `Boole` and `NIntegrate`are combined. Maybe it does here too.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I try  `indicator[a_,b_][x_]` as recommended by @R.M but the results are different. Still working on it.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm not fully convinced by Heike's example there. It probably has to do with the way the OP constructed `Piecewise` vs. `Boole` and wrong constructions can lead to different results. For example, replace `Boole[x + y < .5] f[x, y]` in Heike's example with `g[x, y]`, where `g[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{f[x, y], x + y < 0.5}, {0, True}}]`, and you'll see the same set of points being returned with the same time taken.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming definitions of the functions as in R.M.'s answer we can observe that :

```
{ j1[s], j2[s], finv1[s] } // Simplify
```

> ```
> {6 - 12 s, -12, 1/(s - s^2)}
> ```

To determine the integrand we need the functions : $ I_{(0,s]}(u) - s \quad$  and  $ (I_{(0,s]}(u) - s)(I_{(0,s]}(v) - s)(I_{(0,s]}(w) - s)$, 
 so  we define them this way :

```
indicat[a_, b_, x_] := UnitStep[x - a] UnitStep[b - x] - b

indi[u_, v_, w_, s_] := indicat[0, s, u] indicat[0, s, v] indicat[0, s, w]
```

A more reasonable idea is to use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` and to make use of 
`j2[s]` and `finv1[s]` to define the function `h` :

```
h[u_, v_, w_] :=  12 NIntegrate[1/(s - s^2) indi[u, v, w, s], {s, 0, 1}]
```

It appears that `Integrate` involves some drawbacks, (see e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/bug-in-integrate-for-mathematica/3571#3571)) and it would take much more time. Now we can make 3D-plots of `h` for various arguments, e.g. `w` :

```
Grid[ Table[ Plot3D[ h[u, v, w], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}], {w, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}}]]
```

[image]

It takes rather a long time to make these plots working with definitions of indicators by `Piecewise` as well as by `UnitStep`(approximately the same).

Answer (score 2):

One can calculate the integral observing that `h[u,v,w]` is symmetric in it arguments and that one can split the integration interval in `[0,u]\[Union][u,v]\[Union][v,w]\[Union][w,1]`. In each interval the indicator is either `0` or `1`.
The result is :

```
12 Simplify[Integrate[1/(s - s^2) (UnitStep[u] UnitStep[s - u] - s) (UnitStep[v] UnitStep[s - v] - s) (UnitStep[w] UnitStep[s - w] - s), {s, 0, u}, Assumptions -> {0 < u < 1, 0 < v < 1, 0 < w < 1, u < v < w}] + Integrate[1/(s - s^2) (UnitStep[u] UnitStep[s - u] - s) (UnitStep[v] UnitStep[s - v] - s) (UnitStep[w] UnitStep[s - w] - s), {s, u, v}, Assumptions -> {0 < u < 1, 0 < v < 1, 0 < w < 1, u < v < w}] + Integrate[1/(s - s^2) (UnitStep[u] UnitStep[s - u] - s) (UnitStep[v] UnitStep[s - v] - s) (UnitStep[w] UnitStep[s - w] - s), {s, v, w}, Assumptions -> {0 < u < 1, 0 < v < 1, 0 < w < 1, u < v < w}] + Integrate[1/(s - s^2) (UnitStep[u] UnitStep[s - u] - s) (UnitStep[v] UnitStep[s - v] - s) (UnitStep[w] UnitStep[s - w] - s), {s, w, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < u < 1, 0 < v < 1, 0 < w < 1, u < v < w}]]

(* 12 (-(3/2) + u + v + w + Log[1 - u] - Log[w]) *)

hAux[u_?NumericQ,v_?NumericQ,w_?NumericQ]:=12 (-(3/2)+u+v+w+Log[1-u]-Log[w])
h[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] := hAux[Sequence @@ Sort[{u, v, w}]]
```

[image: plot]