# integrating with multiple indicator functions depending on each other

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, syntax

I need to compute the following integral with three indicator functions, $I(x)$, $I_1(x_1)$ and $I_2(x_2)$,

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1I(x)\left(
 \ I_1(x_1)\,x_{1} + I_2(x_2)\,x_{2}-1
 \right) dx_1 dx_2
$$

where

$$
I(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } I_1(x_1)x_1 + I_2(x_2)x_2 \geq
s \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}%
\end{cases}
$$

$$
I_i(x_i)=%
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x_i \geq t_i \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \qquad i=1,2
$$

I try to write it as

```
Integrate[
(x1 + x2 - 1)*(Boole[x1 + x2 >= s && x1 >= t1 && x2 >= t2]),{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}]
```

It does generate some superficially long output, which makes me further suspect the syntax.

I found at [this place](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/integrating-with-multiple-indicator-functions) a similar problem about multiple indicator functions was also discussed , however, it did not include the above "compound" indicator case.

PS: The original integral is with $n+1$ indicator functions. I simplified it to the above $2+1$ indicator functions with $\textit{U}(0,1)$ case.

Comment: You could write your indicator functions in terms of `UnitStep[x-t]`

Comment: @mikado Thanks for the input. But writing as`Integrate[
(x1 + x2 - 1)*(Boole[x1 + x2 >= s)UnitStep[x1 - t1]UnitStep[x1 - t2],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}]` generate exact the same output. However, if changing to `Integrate[
(x1 + x2 - 1)UnitStep[x1 + x2 -s]UnitStep[x1 - t1]UnitStep[x1 - t2],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}]`, it seems not working, and I am not sure the reason for the later.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding some assumptions (I think the following is reasonable):

```
res = Integrate[(x1 + x2 - 1)*(Boole[
      x1 + x2 >= s && x1 >= t1 && x2 >= t2]), {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}];

FullSimplify[res, 0 < s < 1 && 0 < t1 <= t2 < 1]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{2} (\text{t1}-1) (\text{t2}-1) (\text{t1}+\text{t2}) & s\leq \text{t1}\lor s\leq
>    \text{t1}+\text{t2} \\
>  \frac{1}{6} \left(-2 s^3+3 s^2 (\text{t1}+\text{t2}+1)\\\qquad -6 s (\text{t1}+\text{t2})-\text{t1}^3+3
>    (\text{t1}+\text{t2})-\text{t2}^3\right) & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$$

A faster approach (if you already know what constraints to assume) is this:

```
res = Assuming[0 < s < 1 && 0 < t1 <= t2 < 1, 
  FullSimplify@
   Integrate[(x1 + x2 - 1)*(Boole[
       x1 + x2 >= s && x1 >= t1 && x2 >= t2]), {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]]
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `(0,1)`for all three indicators are very reasonable assumptions; however, I cannot say `t1 <= t2` given the original setting. Also, I guess I can somewhat simplify the problem, but the reason I raised the question here is because I am wandering whether the original syntax is the correct /optimal approach to handle multiple indicators.

Comment: One might also want to perform a preliminary canonicalization with `PiecewiseExpand[]`.